# CryptographicException during Push Sending using JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications

Tags: c#, asp.net, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have tried to send push from my shared server. i am using  JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.dll. my project is in framework 3.5. these are the errors showing.
"

> *An internal error occurred.   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet,
>   SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[]
>   data)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[]
>   rawData)    at
>   JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.NotificationConnection.start(String
>   p12File, String p12FilePassword)    at
>   JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.NotificationConnection..ctor(String
>   host, Int32 port, String p12File, String p12FilePassword)    at
>   JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.NotificationService.set_Connections(Int32
>   value)    at
>   JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.NotificationService..ctor(Boolean
>   sandbox, String p12File, String p12FilePassword, Int32 connections)* "

Comment: Well, based on the errors you got, and without seeing your code, I'm assuming the problem is either with your p12 file or with your password.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the same issue on my server setting the application pool identity (in advanced settings of the app-pool) to LocalSystem.